# 'possible outcomes' definition and interpretation

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am baffled on a practice problem I am doing:
"A fair coin is flipped 25 times, what are the total possible outcomes?"

My question is how do we define and interpret '**possible outcomes**'?

*Interpretation* 1 : 25 + 1 = 26 possible outcomes, as in **counts of heads and tails**. So 1 heads and 24 tails is an outcome, and then 2 heads and 23 tails is another outcome.

*Interpretation* 2 : As a **permutation with repetitions allowed** = (26 ^ 2); So in this case, even if the count of **heads** and **tails** is the same, if they have a different order, it will count as a different 'possible outcome'.

How is it generally accepted to interpret this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Both are valid. It depends on the situation. That said, the second interpretation is more general (it contains all of the information in the first interpretation), so it may be "better". But you're right that the question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

The correct interpretation is probably "possible sequences of heads and tails." (I believe this is what you meant by your second interpretation, but you've incorrectly calculated it.) Each flip has $2$ possible results, and there are $25$ flips, so there are $2^{25}$ possible outcomes.

To see where that comes from, let's consider some cases with fewer flips. If I flip the coin only once, then there are only $2=2^1$ possible outcomes. Flipping it twice doubles the possible outcomes, since I can still flip heads or tails, regardless of the first flip, so there are $4=2^2$ possible outcomes with two flips. More generally, if there are $2^{n-1}$ possible outcomes for $n-1$ flips, then flipping $n$ times again doubles the possible outcomes by the same reasoning, so there are $2\cdot 2^{n-1}=2^n$ possible outcomes with $n$ flips. By induction this holds for all $n$.

As for why I say that the second interpretation is probably what is intended, note that if our outcomes are the possible sequences, then each count (such as "$4$ heads are flipped") is an event. However, if our outcomes are counts, then we cannot (from those outcomes) say anything about particular types of sequences (such as "the first $3$ flips are heads"). We would like for our outcomes to be, in a sense, fundamental--to be able to tell us basically anything about the experiment that we might want to know. The second interpretation allows for that. The first does not.

Comment: The sequences are symmetrical in a way that the counts are not. We can break the counts into smaller distinguishable pieces (the sequences) and when we do so some of the counts (such as no heads) correspond to fewer sequences than others (such as five heads). The sequences are the fundamental outcomes of the experiment. It may be a bit premature (philosophically) to talk of probability.

Comment: That's a fair point. I have edited my answer accordingly.